# Selecting a tag within a specific tag with Javascript

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, associative-array

I have two problems with a small userscript for chrome that I'm trying to put together.
The goal is to find and put together information from a forum.
The structure of the html is similar to the following:

```
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="cfInnerWrapper">
  <div class"inner" title="user1">user1</div>
  <div class="cfMessage">
   <div class="message">  
    This is a message. <strong>the important information 1</strong>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="cfInnerWrapper">
  <div class"inner" title="user2">user2</div>
  <div class="cfMessage">
   <div class="message">  
    This is a message. <strong>the important information 2</strong>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I want to get only the important message within the <strong> and connect it to the user saying it. The important message should also contain a specific string, but that not an issue here. I do this by finding all cfInnerWrapper and then go through them one by one to select the important message-user-pair and saves them in an array.

This is my JS:

```
window.onload = function(){
 var find_str = /important/mi;
 var votes = new Array();
 var message = document.getElementsByClassName('cfInnerWrapper');
 for (m in message){
  var strong_element = message[m].getElementsByTagName('strong'); <---- Error
  if(strong_element){
   var strong_content = strong_element[0].innerHTML;
   if(strong_content.match(find_str)){
    var message_user = message[m].getElementsByClassName('inner')[0].getAttribute('title');
    votes[message_user] = strong_content;
   }
  }
  alert(votes['user1']); <--- Works
 }
 alert(votes['user1']); <--- Doesn't work
}
```

Ok, so this actually works. But my browsers ie Chrome says its an error where I show it.
Is there a better way to select a tag from within the specific tag?

The next problem is that the saved array doesn't seem to be saved outside the for-loop for some reason.
When I alert the content of vote within the for-loop I can access the information. When I try to do it from outside the loop it doesn't work at all. I don't understand why.

Comment: Use a JavaScript library. It'll save you a lot of work. I recommend jQuery.

Comment: You shouldn't use a `for in` loop to iterate over a `nodeList` - see: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/NodeList

Comment: @NathanMacInnes Chrome userscripts doesn't support `@require`, and including a 90+kb library just to do some simple DOM traversal is slightly excessive, isn't it?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I also like jQuery, and will try to learn it more. I choosed normal js here, no reason really. The site that I'm going to use it for actually already imports jQuery, so I think that I could have used it. I just don't really have the skills yet.

Comment: @Yi Jiang, apologies I didn't read the question properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First, you are using `for (item in collection)` construct over an array or an array-like (in this case NodeList) object, which is the main cause of your error.

  This is not the right way to do, and will give you error when you it iterates to the `length` property, which is a number, not an element.

  Instead, you need to use the `for` loop or convert it to an array and then `forEach` on it.
- You are storing `votes` inside an Array, but you are using it like an associative array, you should store them in an Object instead.

  Note that you can use `[]` to create a new Array and `{}` to create a new Object. I mentioned this because you used `new Array()`.
- Using `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` makes your code a bit shorter! You are creating a Chrome userscript and Chrome already supports it.

So here is an improved code which is more readable and works. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GeMp6/)

```
var messages = document.querySelectorAll('.cfInnerWrapper'),
    votes = {},
    pattern = /important/i;

// for each message
for (var i = 0; i < messages.length; i ++) {

    var message = messages[i],
        user = message.querySelector('.inner[title]'),
        strong = message.querySelector('strong');

    // check that the elements exist
    if (user && strong) {

        var userName = user.getAttribute('title'),
            content = strong.innerHTML;

        // check if it matches the pattern
        if (pattern.test(content)) {
            votes[userName] = content;
        }

    }

}
```